# how to upload users portfolio images to same directory and show images on each users profile

Tags: php, image, file

I'm suffering in very common but problem in PHP. I have a website for different user's portfolio. Now what I'm saying is if a single user upload images to directory (one directory for all users) portfolio  if any one will check their portfolio just that user's images will appear on that user portfolio page. databse connection and session are available in the header.php These are my codes..

```html
<?php require_once('inc/header.php');


$_SESSION['user_id'];


?>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-background-color="white" data-active-color="danger">

    <!--
    Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar's background using: data-background-color="white | black"
    Tip 2: you can change the color of the active button using the data-active-color="primary | info | success | warning | danger"
  -->

      <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <?php require_once('inc/text-logo.php');?>
            
            <!-- sidebar Nav -->
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="dashboard.php">
                        <i class="ti-panel"></i>
                        <p>DASHBOARD</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <i class="ti-user"></i>
                        <p>MY PROFILE</p>
                    </a>
                </li> 
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="portfolio.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
                        <p>PORFTOLIO</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="icons.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
                        <p>SOCIAL LINKS</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="notifications.html">
                        <i class="ti-bell"></i>
                        <p>Notifications</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-panel">

<?php require_once('inc/topnav.php');?>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <div class="icon-big icon-danger text-center">
                                            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="numbers">
                      <p>UPLOAD <br> MULTIIMAGES</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="stats">
                                    
                                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
                      $date = date('d-m-Y H:ia');
                      $images = $_FILES['images']['name'];
                      $images_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
                      $uploads_dir = '../uploads';
                    move_uploaded_file($images_tmp, "$uploads_dir/$images");
                      if(empty($images)){
                        $error = "PLEASE SELECT AT LEAST ONE PHOTO.";
                      }
                      else{
                        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `portfolio` (`id`, `date`, `images`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$images', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."')";
                        if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query)){
                          $msg = "IMAGE UPLOADED TO YOUR PORTFOLIO";
                        }
                        else{
                          $error = "IMAGE UPLOADING FAILED, PLEASE CHECK";
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ?>
                                    
                    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <input type="file" name="images" class="form-control" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"><hr>
                      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info">
                    </form>
                                   
                                   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
          </div>
                   
                                    
                                    <?php
                    if(isset($error)){
                  ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <div class="icon-big icon-danger text-center">
                                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="numbers">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="stats">
                                   <?php
                      echo "<center><span style='font-size:12px;color:darkred'><h4>$error</h4></span></center>";
                                   ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end content -->
                        </div>  <!--end card-->
          </div> <!--- end Col -->
                      
                                <?php
                    }
                    else if(isset($msg)){
                  ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        <div class="icon-big icon-danger text-center">
                                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                                        <div class="numbers">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <hr />
                                    <div class="stats">
                                   <?php
                        echo "<center><span style='font-size:12px;color:darkgreen'><h4>$msg</h4></span></center>";
                                   ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end content -->
                        </div>  <!--end card-->
          </div> <!--- end Col -->
               <?php } ?>
                </div> <!-- end row here -->
        </div>
                <div class="row">
                <?php
          $query = "SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' = user_id ORDER BY id DESC";
          $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
          
          if(mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0){
            
          }
          else{
            echo "<center><span class='text-danger'><h3>You Didn't Upload any Portfolio Image Now!</h3></span></center>";
        ?>
          <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
              $id = $row['id'];
              $images = $row['images']['name'];
              $images_tmp = $row['images']['tmp_name'];
              $user_id = $row['user_id'];
          ?>
        
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $images;?>" width="200px" alt="<?php echo $user_fullname;?>" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
        <?php } }?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<?php require_once('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking - what is your _specific_ question/problem? Please go read [ask].

Comment: is it not specific, if  I knows to show clearly my problems so why i need to come here..? to waist my time...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options

1) Save the name of the user's images in the database and when displaying the portfolio get them and display them. (I recommend)

2) Create a folder for each user or portfolio

3) Make a mark in the name of the image when saving is acceptable user12__filename.jpg. And when displaying receive files via the `glob('/images/user'.$id.'__*')` function